# Is there an easier way to view json object from firefox or chrome's developer console?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

What is the easiest way to read json from Firefox or Chrome's developer console? Do I need to install a plugin? Or hopefully there's a javascript function that lets you view json in a way that's much easier to read...

For example. If I try console.log(data) where data is the json object, the developer console displays it like a one huge chunk of string instead of displaying the structure, so it's really hard to sift through and filter out what I want.

EDIT:
I apologize for the confusion I caused. I just checked Chrome and it seems Chrome does display JSON in a structured way. However on Firefox it's all jumbled together. I attached the screenshot. I guess the question is "Is there a way to display this in a more structured way like on Chrome?", and as I learned from below, I guess console.dir() takes care of this. Then my last question would be: Is this an intended behavior?

[image: console.log(data) from Firefox]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firebug and Webkits developer tools display **any** object, structured and well readable.
It seems like you try to output a *JSON string* instead an object. If thats the case, just parse it into an object before

```
console.log( JSON.parse( data ) );
```

and by the way, there are lots of neat methods on the `console` object, like `console.dir()` which directly lists an object properties/keys.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading question. It already is in JSON format. Thanks for pointing me to console.dir(). It kind of solved the problem but for some reason it only displays three lines and is extremely difficult to navigate. Is this normal?

Comment: @Vlad: I don't think I can imagine the problem. It might be a great idea you upload a screenshot from your console.

Comment: @downvote: please help me and the rest of this community and allow us to share your wisdom.

Comment: I didn't like that "excuse me?". Teach, do not scold. If OP knew the answer, he wouldn't have posted the question. You don't like it, ignore it.

Comment: On second view. I should had ignored your tone. So I'm contradicting myself.

Answer (score 7):

There are no JSON objects.

There are

- Javascript object
- JSON data as Javascript string

If you want to display JSON as string in an easily browseable manner do

```
  var obj = JSON.parse(jsonstring);
  console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 2):

What version of Chrome are you using? When I `console.log` an object, it is displayed as an object where you can expand properties, not a string. (Chrome 16.0.912.77). Are you parsing the JSON before logging it or just logging the JSON string?

[image]

Comment: Ah I apologize for causing the trouble. I've been actually coding on Firefox and firefox seems to display the results in an unstructured way. I just checked Chrome and indeed it works well like your attached screenshot. I'm sorry about this. Will edit the question.